# Load a Propertie File

Tags: java, properties, filepath

I have something like this as Code, and it works fine but how
but i want replace the absolute path with System.getProperty("user.dir");
but this gives me back a string with backslahses how can i resolve it,
or replace this so that converts this to c:/........

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

         String strPropertiePath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
         System.out.println("strPropertiePath "+strPropertiePath);


         String absoluthPath2Propertie = "C:/Users/maurice/Dropbox/a_projectturkey/solution_06_09_2014/Application_Propertie/logging.properties";

     File fileLog = new File(absoluthPath2Propertie);
     LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(absoluthPath2Propertie));
     //ConfigSystem.setup();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `File` or `Path` objects with proper parent-child relations. You do not need to care about slashes and blackslashes, `File` and `Path` will take care about them for you.

E.g. to define a property file which sits in the user dir folder in a subfolder of `props` and having a file name `myprops.properties`, you can use it like this:

```
File propFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
    "/props/myprops.properties");
```

And you can load this property file like this:

```
// Use try-with-resources to properly close the file input stream
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFile)) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in);
}
```

**Edit:**

So if you need a file named `logging.properties` in your user dir, simply use this:

```
File propFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
    "logging.properties");
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFile)) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in);
}
```

Comment: user.dir gives me back: C:\Users\maurice\Dropbox\a_projectturkey\solution_06_09_2014\Application_Propert‌​ie

Comment: but i need the following, path: C:/Users/maurice/Dropbox/a_projectturkey/solution_06_09_2014/Application_Propert‌​ie/logging.properties"

Comment: the solution is may, simple but i dont know how i can, prepare the string of user.dir so that i do get: c:/..../..../ –

Comment: Edited, added your specific case. You do not need to care about slashes and blackslashes, `File` will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to load the property file.

```
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    properties.load(in);

    properties.get("user.dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the system filesystem path delimiter with the following piece of code:

```
System.getProperties("file.separator")
```

By using this you will be able to create a correct path on any supported platform. Such that you can use slashes in UNIX/Linux based systems and backslashes on Windows.

Comment: user.dir gives me back: C:\Users\maurice\Dropbox\a_projectturkey\solution_06_09_2014\Application_Propertie

Comment: but i need the following, path: C:/Users/maurice/Dropbox/a_projectturkey/solution_06_09_2014/Application_Propertie/logging.properties"

Comment: the solution is may, simple but i dont know how i can, prepare the string of user.dir so that i do get: c:/..../..../